# Touch.rawPosition - Touch.Position instead of Touch.position - (previously saved) Touch.position?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Let's say my aim is to get the length of a swipe movement using the Touch class.

what is the difference between using

```
 if(touchPhase == touchPhase.Began)
    {
    touchStart = touch.Position;
    }
    else if(touchPhase == touchPhase.Ended) {
    Vector2 length = touch.Position - touchStart;
    }
```

and

```
if(touchPhase == touchPhase.Ended) {
    Vector2 length = touch.RawPosition - touch.Position;
    }
```

From the documentation ,the rawPosition doesn't change when the touch contact is dragged, so the code should work.

I need a small explanation about that.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the behavior should be equal. As you say yourself [`Touch.RawPosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-rawPosition.html) is the

> first position of the touch contact in screen space pixel coordinates.
>
> Raw position returns the original position of a touch contact and doesn't change as the touch is dragged. If you need the current position of the touch see `Touch.position`.

**Except** in your second snippet it should rather be

```c#
Vector2 length = touch.Position - touch.RawPosition;
```

The delta is always the **current minus** the **previous** position.

---

You can simply proof check yourself using e.g.

```c#
// In general rather use switch for enums
switch(touchPhase)
{
    case TouchPhase.Began:
        touchStart = touch.Position;
        break;

    case TouchPhase.Ended:
        Debug.Assert(touchStart == touch.RawPosition, "Not equal :O", this);
        Vector2 length = touch.Position - touchStart;
        Vector2 length2 = touch.Position - touch.RawPosition;
        // Obviously redundant - if the first assert already passed then this will as well
        Debug.Assert(length == length2, "Not equal :O", this)
        break;
}
```